Why doesn't the telegram bot receive some messages from the channel?
I have a telegram bot that is added as an administrator to a telegram channel. When I tested all messages were received and everything worked perfectly, but on a real channel, some messages are received and processed, and some are not even logged, that is, the bot does not receive them. Why is this and how to fix it?
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@dp.channel_post_handler(chat_id='-1002066994207')
async def handle_channel_post_1(event: types.Message):
    # Process messages from channel 1
    text = event.text
    logger.info(f"Received message: {text}")

    pattern = {
        "pair": r"Пара:\s*([\w/]+)",
        "direction": r"Направление:\s*(\w+)",
        "leverage": r"Плечо:\s*(\d+)x",
        "entry_price": r"Вход:\s*([\d.]+)",
        "stop_loss": r"Стоп:\s*([\d.]+)",
        "take_profits": r"Тейки:\s*([\d.;\s]+)",
    }

    valid_signal = True
    extracted_data = {}

    for key, regex in pattern.items():
        match = re.search(regex, text)
        if match:
            if key == "take_profits":
                # Split the take profits by semicolons and remove any extra whitespace
                extracted_data[key] = [tp.strip() for tp in match.group(1).split(';') if tp.strip()]
            else:
                extracted_data[key] = match.group(1)
        else:
            valid_signal = False

    if valid_signal:
        logger.info(f"Extracted data: {extracted_data}")
        users = get_active_users_with_keys()
        for user in users:
            position = binance_open_position(extracted_data, user[3], user[4], user[5], user[7])
            if position != 0:
                update_balance(user[1], position * -1)


def get_active_users_with_keys():
    try:
        # Connect to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Execute the query
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE api_key IS NOT NULL
              AND api_secret IS NOT NULL
              AND bot_active = 1
              AND exchange = 'Binance'
              AND position_size != 0;
        ''')

        # Fetch all results
        users = cursor.fetchall()

        # Log the result
        logger.info(f"Fetched {len(users)} active users with keys.")
        return users

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        logger.error(f"SQLite error: {e}")

    finally:
        # Close the connection
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

